# Probability of 1 dice rolled N times

Tags: probability, dice

In this scenario, N = 3. The dice has 6 faces.

I want to know what is the probability of rolling a 4,5,6 in only a single dice when rolled three times regardless of order.

I understand that [4,5,6]/6 is 3/6 where in there is 50% chance of rolling it. I also understand that there is a 12.5% chance of rolling 4,5,6 in each dice when rolled three times. (correct me if I'm wrong here)

Comment: Would you mind to start by stating **what the actual problem is**, and not what you understand after reading it? (keep in mind that we haven't read it).

Comment: i updated the question

Comment: Is the order important?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  Are you asking "what is the probability that I roll at least one of $4,5,6$ in three tries with a fair die?"  or are you asking something else?

Comment: So you have 3 rolls and you are interested in knowing the probability of rolling one of 4,5,6 exactly one time (meaning that you roll one of 1,2,3 the other times). Said another way, you have an experiment which succeeds with a probability of 1/2, you repeat this experiment 3 times and you are interested in the probability of exactly one success. This is equal to $\operatorname{Pr}(X = 1)$ where $X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(0.5,3)$. Look up the Binomial distribution.

Comment: @lulu yes something like that

Comment: @andrew thanks i look that up. will also try to understand the equation you gave me.

Comment: Something like that, or exactly that?  do you consider the sequence $4,4,4$ to be a success or a failure?

Comment: 4,4,4 is a failure, assuming that these are the values for each die. just like andrew said, im only interested in knowing the probability of rolling one of [4,5,6] in a single roll of a die. i dont care of the other rolls if I already have 4,5 or 6.

Comment: The **actual** problem seems pretty clear. Clearer than several of the Comments.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the question is clear enough, even if OP's initial attempt at an
answer is not productive. (Joined by authors of several unhelpful comments.)

The probability of getting `456` in exactly that order is $1/6^3$,
similarly for getting `546`, and so on. So the answer is $3!/6^3 = 1/36.$

For doubters, here is a simulation, in R statistical software, of a million such experiments, which should be accurate to about two or three places. (There are more efficient ways to program this, but maybe the one shown is among the easiest to follow.)

```
m = 10^6; n = 3; yes=logical(m)
for (i in 1:m) {
   faces = sample(1:6, n, repl=T)
   f4 = sum(faces==4); f5 = sum(faces==5);  f6=sum(faces==6)
   yes[i] = (f4==1 & f5==1 & f6==1) }
mean(yes);  1/36
## 0.027463     # aprx prob of event
## 0.02777778   # exact probability
```